COUNTIF two indexes match to return counts of their rows
TableI want excel to display the following:
Count the number of rows with a date filled in when a cell from one table is equal to a cell in a different table column.
For example,
With R9 containing the value 8 and column A having many 8's, I want excel to count the number of sales date values in all rows where these values match. In this scenario there are 9 rows where cell R9 is equal to values in column A that have a sales date shown.
Edit: I would like this all to go in column Z under sold count.

That isn't even remotely an MRE. Your question is incomprehensible.

sorry I am not sure what an MRE is. I just got an account here today because I was having trouble with column Z. Column Z2 through Z8 should all return 0, but Z9 should return 9. It should return 9 because there are 9 cells in column O that have a sales date where the indexes on both tables match.

Assuming Column A is your ID column and Column C contains the date values, you can use this formula:
=COUNTIFS(A2:A18,H3,C2:C18, "<>")

Here, H3 refers to the ID that you want to check for. The "<>" simply counts all rows that are not blank. Please adjust the ranges and column references to match your sheet.
